# When starting an .exe file using batch !! an error window pops up

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

---

```
rem thx to rbi

title starter

set /a coutx=0

:startthetrigger

set /a coutx+=1

if %coutx%==20 goto done

start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%coutx%mm.exe   

start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%coutx%mm.exe

start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%coutx%mm.bat 

goto startthetrigger

:done

pause 

 exit
```

while starting an .exe file using batch !! an error window pops up, saying that "windows cannot find " !!

my problem is 
   how to skip or reject this error message !! this my code below!!
  if you want you see this picture through this link for more information!!

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/QSOKDkjOLMAUiAgkg-5-8p18CnVDorH3JHoyn5uom8k=w643-h348-no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does what you need:

```
@echo off
set "name=logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35"
rem thx to rbi
title starter
set /a coutx=0
:startthetrigger
set /a coutx+=1
if %coutx%==20 goto done

if exist %name%%coutx%mm.exe start /REALTIME %name%%coutx%mm.exe   
if exist %name%%coutx%mm.exe start /REALTIME %name%%coutx%mm.exe
if exist %name%%coutx%mm.bat start /REALTIME %name%%coutx%mm.bat 

goto startthetrigger
:done
pause 
 exit
pause
```

Comment: thank you very much !! you fixed my problem !! and also my code smaller and smarter!! thx again!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, start by using the right syntax.

```
Set /a coutx+=1
```

Or

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,20) do (
    start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%%amm.exe   
    start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%%amm.exe
    start /REALTIME logtemp.microsoft_backupimg63464343fb1F7195290E2D8.TMPx35%%amm.bat 
)
```

Comment: oh !thx !! a small typing error !! !!

Comment: i have edit my post a bit!! i am waiting for your answer!!